# Assert that an object can be serialized using joblib

Tags: python, serialization, scikit-learn, joblib

I want to test whether an object can be serialized using `joblib`(!). Something like:

```py
assert pickle.dumps(my_obj)
```

seems to be the way using `pickle` but `joblib` doesn't provide `.dumps`. I tried to do:

```py
with tempfile.TemporaryFile("wb") as f:
        assert joblib.dump(my_obj, f)
```

But this fails because `joblib.dump` returns `None` in this case (although according to the [doc](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html) it should return something which evaluates to `True`).

What would be the equivalent if I'm using `joblib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source, nothing is returned if you pass in a file object, only if you pass in a file name. https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/numpy_pickle.py#L510

So using a named temp file and passing on the name should do the trick.

Running the code and doing the assert on the file size seems also a valid strategy.

Comment: I opened [this](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/997). Thanks!